# How to populate data from API and load into dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

I am working on MVC application that uses API and i want to call a method from the API so that it will load the data to the combo-box. I have no idea on how i can tackle this as am new this.

Thanks.

`ClaimController` function from the API which got this function.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Claim")]
[Route("GetScheme")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetScheme()
{
    try
    {

        using (IBusinessLogic logic = new BusinessLogic.Implementation.BusinessLogic())
        {
            Request.Headers.Clear();
            var tmpresults = logic.GetScheme();
            var results = (from x in tmpresults.Result select new { text = x.Description, value = x.Id }).ToArray();
            var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

Views from the Client which is the UI
I want to call that function from API to load the data into the combo-box

```
    function GetAllScheme() {
    var select = $("#ddlScheme");

    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:55393/_Api/Claim",

        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            var datavalue = data;
            var serverResponse = datavalue;
            contentType: "application/json";
            $.each(serverResponse, function (i, serverResponse)
            {
                select.append("<option value='" + serverResponse.Description + "'>" + serverResponse.Description + "</option>")

            });

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Dropdown

```
<select class="dropdown form-control input-xs required" id="ddlScheme" onclick="GetAllScheme()(this)">
                                                                 <select 
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: The AJAX request looks ok, the HTML for the select looks funky though

Comment: @JohnMc I have placed a break point and it is not firing every time i select the drop down. The drop-down it's empty.

Comment: @Ozrix What's the problem? can you correct me. thanks

Comment: check out my answer, might help

Comment: Shouldn't your url be `http://localhost:55393/api/claim/getcheme` ? Can you even hit the api?

Answer (score 0):

You have to append option elements into your select (dropdown) element after you get the server response. Something like this:

```
    function GetAllScheme() {
        // get the dropwdown by its id
        var select = $("#ddlScheme");

        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(myJsonObject, function (i, mobj) {
                    $("#Cartbl").append('<tr><td width="50px">' + mobj.Description + '</td></tr>');

                    // for each element, add an option into the dropdown
                    select.append('<option>"+ mobj.Description +"</option>')
                }
            });
            ...
        )}
```

See jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n4mtj9om/

Comment: Must i copy it as it is?

Comment: no, the important bits are those that have comments above them. the point is that you need to search for the dropdown element first, save it into a variable, and then, after successfully getting the ajax request, appending the options into that dropdown

Comment: Am getting this error ://now it is opening <!DOCTYPE html> everytime i click the dropdown

Comment: replace $.each(serverResponse, function (i, serverResponse) with $.each(serverResponse, function (i, item)

Comment: another question, what is returned from the server? is it a collection of items for the dropdown, or something else?

Comment: It is still opening <!DOCTYPE html>  when i click on the dropdown. it is a collection

Comment: replace it in the select.append("<option value='" + serverResponse.Description as well

Comment: Am getting the same error which is the <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: just change it to select.append("<option value='" + item.Value + '">"+ item.Description +"</option>" );

Answer (score 0):

If use Chrome enter in developers tools a see how response the server put a breakpoint after server response because when use maybe 
put this

```
function GetAllScheme() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:32359/api/Claim",

        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data.responseJSON, function(i, mobj) {
            $("#Cartbl").append('<tr><td width="50px">' + mobj.Description +
              '</td></tr>');
          });

        },
        error: function(xhr) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
      });

    }
```